# Cannot open Ubuntu through Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, ram

I've tried repeatedly opening Ubuntu through VirtualBox. I went to the Ubuntu website and downloaded their 64-bit ISO file. Everything goes well when I'm configuring the virtual machine until I start it. I have more than enough memory allocated to the virtual machine, so that shouldn't be the issue. I don't know why I can't open it up.

This has been frustrating me all day and has put a hitch in an assignment.

[image: See the error code here]

Comment: Your problem is with Virtualbox running in the Windows host, not Ubuntu. The error suggests you may be assigning too much resources to the VM so check that before anything else. NEVER assign more than 50% of the host resources, that's a basic rule.

Comment: Please be specific; "*more than enough memory*" means what?  We can't know if you checked the minimum requirements for your *unstated* Ubuntu Desktop release & thus met those requirements, as what you said is *vague* and assumes you look up those requirements & met them. Please provide specific details as your wording doesn't rule out user-procedure errors given lack of detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try one or more of the following to solve `The instruction at ... referenced memory at ... The memory could not be read.` error.

- Add more virtual memory to the guest OS, but not more than half of the physical RAM. (It has already been tried and didn't work, but I repeated it anyway for the sake of completeness.)
- Add more virtual CPU cores to the guest OS, but not more than half of the real physical CPU cores.
- Disable 3D acceleration on the guest OS.